# Is there a math mistake in Moby Dick Chapter 99?

Tags: moby-dick, herman-melville

In Chapter 99 ("The Doubloon") of Moby Dick, Flask comments that the doubloon is worth 16 dollars, and, at two cents a cigar, that will get him 960 cigars.  But if each cigar is two cents, then you can buy 50 for a dollar.  50 x 16 = 800, which isn't 960.  Is this a math mistake on the part of the author, or a deliberate inclusion?

Comment: I interpret this as him having a plan to haggle a discount for bulk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The analysis in [Cliffsnotes](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/literature/m/mobydick/summary-and-analysis/chapters-99100) assumes that this is intended to portray the character's lack of mathematical proficiency:

> Others see things they value as they peruse the coin, but they don't see themselves. The devout first mate, Starbuck, sees the Trinity. Stubb sees temporary wealth and mystery. **Flask reveals his inability with simple math as he miscalculates how many of his beloved cigars he could buy with the doubloon.** The coin reminds Queequeg of his tattoos and homeland. The "ghost-devil" Fedallah bows to the sun that he worships. Little Pip speaks in metaphors but seems to notice a universal human longing in the coin's images. For this moment, the doubloon is the center of the ship, its "navel."
>
> (My emphasis)